# Embedded powershell script in c# Install-SPUserSolution not recognosed

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to run powershell scripts by embedding them in  C# code inorder to activate a (.wsp) template feature on a Sharepoint site.
My Code is as follows

```
Command installCommand = new Command("Install-SPUserSolution");
installCommand.Parameters.Add("identity", "Template.wsp");
installCommand .Parameters .Add ("site", "siteURL");
// create Powershell runspace 
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

// open it 
runspace.Open()

// create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(" Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell");

pipeline.Commands.Add(installCommand);
//added just for reference since command dosen’t return anything
pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

// execute the script 
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
//(This part of the code throws error saying Install-SPUserSolution is not a recognized cmdlet,function,script,…)

  // close the runspace 
 runspace.Close();
```

Notes:

1. I have tried adding the whole command as a script, but I get the
   same error.
2. I have tried the script in SharePoint management shell
   command prompt and it works perfectly there.
3. I am using the above
   code in a Library Class of a WCF.
4. All my platforms of every
   sub-Project in Visual Studio is  set to “ANY CPU” and i am using
   .net framework 3.5.
5. I have also checked the help option available
   in management shell and the command “Install-SPUserSolution” indeed
   exists as a cmdlet of Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell.
6. I am using
   Client Object Model(COM) to complete my task, hence cannot use C#
   code to activate feature since COM doesn’t support it.

I am completely clueless as to what I might be doing wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the solution to my problem,
Since i was trying to run this code on a WCF,aLL i had to do was
add the spadmin account to my application pool,where the wcf was hosted,
use sp.elevatepriviledges delegate
and turnh of impersonation